# set font-size according to the body width with css3

Tags: css, responsive-design, font-size

I want to set the `font-size` of `<body>` to be 5% of the width of itself(`body`).

Is there a pure css3 way to do this?

I'm doing this with jquery now, but I want it simpler:

```
$(function() {

    var $body = $('body');

    function adjust_font_size() {
        $body.css('font-size', $body.width()*0.05+'px');
    }
    adjust_font_size();
    $(window).resize(adjust_font_size);


});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `<body>` tag has the **same width as the viewport**, you can use `vw` units :

> vw : 1/100th of the width of the viewport.( [source MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths))

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/HtL7m/)**

```
body{
    font-size:5vw;
}
```

If your `<body>` tag has a **percentage width**, `vw` units  will work too (considering the `<html>` tag doesn't have a fixed width).

Example :

```
body{ 
    width:50%; /* = 100% / 2 */
    font-size:2.5vw; /* = 5vw / 2 */
}
```

If your body tag has a **fixed width** (in px, em... units), font-size set with `vw` won't adapt to it's width.

---

Browser support for vw units is IE9+, [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units) for more info.

Comment: This depends on whether the OP actually meant to say "viewport" and not "body", unless they have a very specific reason to make the font size relative to the `body` element and not the viewport. I'm inclined to believe the former, even though the OP repeatedly makes references to the `body` element specifically.

Comment: @BoltClock I added some info about that in my answer.